# Gibbs sampler -transformation of conditional posterior

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, posterior, gibbs

If my conditional posterior $\pi(\sigma^{-2}|\mathbf{y
},\mu)\sim Gamma(a,b)$, how can  I get the conditional posterior $\pi(\sigma^{2}|\mathbf{y
},\mu)$ with a transformation? The reason I ask is that the question asked to find the latter posterior but gave the prior $\pi(\sigma^{-2})$. I would really appreciated your help

Comment: Do you know about the inverse Gamma family of distributions?

Comment: Ive had a look. I tried it but the teacher said that we didn't need any other packages to add in R (i.e don't need to download InvGamma). I am guessing $\frac{1}{gamma(a,b)}$ wouldn't work?

Comment: What is it you're trying to obtain, exactly? The pdf? the pdf of the inverse is simple algebra. I'm guessing that you should know how to obtain the [pdf of a transformed r.v.](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157) in terms of the pdf of the original variable (as a function of the inverse-tranformed new variable) and the Jacobian.

Answer (score 0):

If  $\sigma^{-2}\vert \textbf{y}$, $\mu$ is Gamma($a,b$) then $\sigma^2\vert \mathbb{y}, \mu$ will be inverse-Gamma($a,b$).
The way to get this answer is to [apply the change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution#Derivation_from_Gamma_distribution) so that $\tau^2 = \sigma^{-2}$ and we change the measure to be a measure on $\tau^2$.